# TextView Widget Not Updating

Tags: android, android-widget

My TextView Widget is not updating on the home screen.

The new value of the text does not appear on the widget but the old value still remains as it was. This is my code for the widget class and activity that calls the widget update:

```
 public class MotivappWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {

        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewAll.class);
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent
                .getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget);

        // updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_text, input);
        updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_text, pending);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, updateViews);

    }



 public class ViewAll extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
            @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.all_view);
        }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        updateWidgetText();
    }

        private void updateWidgetText() {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
            View vi_widgy = inflater.inflate(R.layout.widget, null); //there is a layout xml file called widget.xml already made
            TextView tv_widgy = (TextView) vi_widgy.findViewById(R.id.widget_text); //in widget.xml, there is a text view called widget_text
            tv_widgy.setText("Text has just changed."); //this text never appears on the widget home even after updating
            updateAllWidgets();
        }

        private void updateAllWidgets(){
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(this, MotivappWidget.class));
            if (appWidgetIds.length > 0) {
                new MotivappWidget().onUpdate(this, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
            }
        }

    }
```